# Проблемы с работой GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8

В базе данных есть последовательность `seq2`. В своем классе-сущности назначил эту последовательность как генератор:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_gen", sequenceName = "seq2")
private int id;
```

В базе данных в качестве генератора тоже вручную установил эту последовательность (до этого была стандартная инкрементация). Но вот проблема, при попытке добавить экземпляр класса в БД, вылетает исключение:

```
    Исключение!org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=models.User]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dao.UserDao.save(UserDao.java:18)
    at services.UserService.saveUser(UserService.java:21)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Однако, если в СУБД написать это через `INSERT`, то все работает. Думал думал, поставил в классе обратно `GenerationType.IDENTITY`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
```

Теперь все работает... но не так. Теперь записи добавляются, причем используется именно последовательность `seq2`, т.к. я ее в БД вручную изменил. Так вот, так ведь не должно быть? Если есть тип `SEQUENCE`, то почему для использования моей последовательности, мне надо использовать `IDENTITY`? Или это работает, только Hibernate самостоятельно создает БД по твоей сущности? Или я что-то делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq2", sequenceName = "seq2", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 10000)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq2")
//    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "integer default nextval('seq2')")
private int id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "RM_SEQ", sequenceName = "ROOM_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "RM_SEQ")
@Column(name = "ID")
public long getId() {
  return id;
  }
```